# AirForAndroid: Flash CS6 can publish android apps only with small icons

Tags: android, flash, air, icons, flash-cs6

I believe a question like this has been posted before, but no answer was found. So I thought I'll ask it again a bit more precise ... and more recent:

I'm using Adobe Flash CS6 to make android apps. But the publishing process in flash (and the descriptor xml) only allows for icons of 3 sizes: 36x36, 48x48 and 72x72. This looks like this:

```
<icon> 
    <image36x36>assets/icon36.png</image36x36> 
    <image48x48>assets/icon48.png</image48x48> 
    <image72x72>assets/icon72.png</image72x72> 
</icon>
```

In previos AirSDK versions (3.4 and 3.5) this was less of a problem, since the app icons where at least somehow always scaled to fit the normal app sice of the android device. With newer AirSDKs however they just remain as they are, which is incredibly small on newer devices.

So I guess I have to either re-enable this scale-to-fit thingie (which I think I won't be able to) or need to add more icons, like 96x96 and 144x144. Problem is, Flash CS6 (with AirSDK 15) has no option for more than those 3 sizes, and when I write it in the xml file myself (and lock it), Flash CS6 can't compile it and gives the error:

"application descriptor file cannot be parsed"

Is there anybody who has either dealt with, and/or knows how to work around that issue? Cause right now I'm stuck, since I've always compiled my AirForAndroidApps this way, and I need the newest version of the SDK for my ANEs to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

thanks in advance,
ANB_Seth

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... silly me ... I've found an answer ... actually it has also already been posted, but I didnt get it really. Now I do ... and to clarify:

yes, you can and have to add these icons via the descriptor file. But before you do that, go into the "Air publish" settings in flash. Here, right on page 1, there is the "include files" section. Add your icon pngs there. Hit OK and exit this settings, open the descriptor with an editor outside of flash and write in the files like I posted above. Close. Save. Make it write protected. No go to flash and publish.